# to check cron is installed on AIX machine or not?

Tags: cron, jobs, aix

I am working on AIX machine with ksh shell. I just wanted to know whether cron is installed on my machine or not. Is there any way to check?

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on https://superuser.com OR https://unix.stackexchange.com . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here.Good Luck

Comment: 1. Yes, it is installed. 2. `if -x /usr/bin/crontab; then echo Ok; fi`

Comment: Correction: `if test -x /usr/bin/crontab; then echo Ok; fi`

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond thank you, it works

Answer (score 0):

Just query if it is installed

```
lslpp -L | grep -i cron
```